# how to Resolve SSLError in aws lambda-rekognition

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

We are getting
`SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e) botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://rekognition.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory` when we are trying to access aws rekignition face service with AWS lambda

following is our flask python code,

```
rek_client = boto3.client('rekognition',
                          aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
                          aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
                          region_name='ap-south-1')
```

Our flask application is working completely fine on localhost even the rekogntion face service is working on locally hosted flask but it's giving SSL error when its get deploy on lamda

Comment: The error is from lambda of flask?

Comment: yes,this same is working on localhost very fine,but when we are deploying it on lamda its giving SSL error

Comment: Which lambda runtime do you use? Python 3.8? have you tried in different region and/or different runtime?